# How to loop through a set, while removing items from the set in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, iteration

Here is my situation:

I have a `list/set` (doesn't matter which) of `movieplayer` objects that I want to call a `"preload"` function on.  This preload function could return immediately but would like return a bit in the future.

I want to store this collection of movieplayers, indicating that they have not been preloaded yet, then loop through them, calling the `preload` function.  The `preload` function, when returned, would remove them from the collection (so I would know when they are all preloaded).

However, I think because python is waiting for the `preload` function, then removing the player, I am getting a `set size changed during iteration error`.

Hey is a simplified version of my code, I would appreciate a way to navigate this issue.

```
a = set([mp1, mp2 mp3])
for player in a:
    preload(player)

# preload would be something like
def preload(player):
    player.preloadVideo()
    a.remove(player)
    # This is where I believe the error gets generated.
```

The only solution that I can think of would be to make a `copy` of the `set a`, and then iterate through that, but I am not sure if that is the right way to do it or would even work.

Comment: Your preload function has two responsibilities, that's one too many

Comment: Please post code that actually exhibits the problem - I believe that it should be `for player in a: preload(player)`.

Comment: @PeterWood I think I like where you are going with this but could you elaborate a little?

Comment: @mhawke You were right, I edited my code, I can't reproduce the exact code because it relies on a movie player and python player embedded in an external program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix it by iterating over a copy of the set. I've used `list()` here:

```
a = set(['mp1', 'mp2', 'mp3'])

# preload would be something like
def preload(player):
    player.preloadVideo()
    a.remove(player)

for player in list(a):
    preload(player)    # N.B. pass player, not a
```

This, however, is not a great design. For one thing the global variable, `a` is referenced from within the `preload()` function. Furthermore, the for loop iterates over all elements of the set passing each in turn to `preload()`, so it is not necessary to check membership of each `player` in `a`. Lastly, `preload()` should perform whatever is required to preload the player, but it should not be responsible for maintaining an external data structure (`a`).

A better design is for `preload()` to return a boolean indicating whether the preload was successful or not. Removal of a successfully loaded player can then be done outside of the preload function:

```
a = set(['mp1', 'mp2', 'mp3'])

# preload would be something like
def preload(player):
    return player.preloadVideo()    # assume that this returns boolean

for player in list(a):
    if preload(player):
        a.remove(player)

if len(a):
    print "{} player(s) failed to preload: {}".format(len(a), a)        
else:
    print "All players successfully preloaded"
```

This code will only remove a player once it has been successfully preloaded.

Comment: This looks great. Are the `id`s of the players in the new list the same as their corresponding players in a?  I.e. would `is` evaluate to true?

Comment: @Startec yes, they're the same objects.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to loop over your list 2 time! as you said, it will raise a `size changed` error.So instead you can use `pop` property of `set` and `list` to get those items which return the value and remove it from your data structure.For a list you can pass the 0 index to `pop` in each iteration also as a more pythoinc way you can use `while` instead of `for` when you want to remove item from your data structure :

```
a = [mp1, mp2 mp3]
while a:
    preload(a.pop(0))
```

But for `set` the pop doesn't accept the index:

```
a = set([mp1, mp2 mp3])
while a:
    preload(a.pop())
```

Example :

```
>>> def preload(i):
...   print i
... 
>>> a=[1,2,3]
>>> while a:
...     preload(a.pop(0))
... 
1
2
3
>>> a
[]
>>> a={1,2,3}
>>> while a:
...     preload(a.pop())
... 
1
2
3
>>> a
set([])
```

Comment: `.pop()` is the right choice here, as said by @Kasra it will work on `list` and `set` (and more) and you don't waste anything in copy.

Comment: fwiw: you can also omit the `0` when popping from a list - which will then pop from the end of the list. Order doesn't seem to matter...

Comment: @Kasra, doesn't this method immediately remove the item from the list or set?  I only want them to be removed when the preload function is done (because there may be an error and I would need to know which player did not preload)

Comment: @Startec Yeah that's right! but in this case since the order is matter we can't do that!

Comment: @Startec So for that aim you can check for existence of a item in the list or `set`! If it was in the `set` it means that the item doesn't been preload!

Answer (score 0):

> but would like return a bit in the future.

If you want to call the preload function asynchronously, I’d use the [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) module:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

a = set([mp1, mp2, mp3])

def preload(player):
    try: # Change it to if/else depending on your type of error handling
        player.preload()
    except:
        return player

p = Pool(5) # uses 5 threads to do the computation, change it accordingly
uninitialized = {players for players in p.map(preload, a) if player is not None}
p.close()
```